# using jquery to get a time picker

Tags: jquery, html, css

I do not know jquery. I was looking for a `time picker` when I found this script. Can anyone please help me, on how should I utilize this code to get the time picker in my html page.

```
/* jQuery timepicker
 * replaces a single text input with a set of pulldowns to select hour, minute, and am/pm
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007 Jason Huck/Core Five Creative (http://www.corefive.com/)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) 
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 *
 * Version 1.0
 */

(function($){
    jQuery.fn.timepicker = function(){
        this.each(function(){
            // get the ID and value of the current element
            var i = this.id;
            var v = $(this).val();

            // the options we need to generate
            var hrs = new Array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12');
            var mins = new Array('00','15','30','45');
            var ap = new Array('am','pm');

            // default to the current time
            var d = new Date;
            var h = d.getHours();
            var m = d.getMinutes();
            var p = (h >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am');

            // adjust hour to 12-hour format
            if(h > 12) h = h - 12;

            // round minutes to nearest quarter hour
            for(mn in mins){
                if(m <= parseInt(mins[mn])){
                    m = parseInt(mins[mn]);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // increment hour if we push minutes to next 00
            if(m > 45){
                m = 0;

                switch(h){
                    case(11):
                        h += 1;
                        p = (p == 'am' ? 'pm' : 'am');
                        break;

                    case(12):
                        h = 1;
                        break;

                    default:
                        h += 1;
                        break;
                }
            }

            // override with current values if applicable
            if(v.length == 7){
                h = parseInt(v.substr(0,2));
                m = parseInt(v.substr(3,2));
                p = v.substr(5);
            }

            // build the new DOM objects
            var output = '';

            output += '<select id="h_' + i + '" class="h timepicker">';             
            for(hr in hrs){
                output += '<option value="' + hrs[hr] + '"';
                if(parseInt(hrs[hr]) == h) output += ' selected';
                output += '>' + hrs[hr] + '</option>';
            }
            output += '</select>';

            output += '<select id="m_' + i + '" class="m timepicker">';             
            for(mn in mins){
                output += '<option value="' + mins[mn] + '"';
                if(parseInt(mins[mn]) == m) output += ' selected';
                output += '>' + mins[mn] + '</option>';
            }
            output += '</select>';              

            output += '<select id="p_' + i + '" class="p timepicker">';             
            for(pp in ap){
                output += '<option value="' + ap[pp] + '"';
                if(ap[pp] == p) output += ' selected';
                output += '>' + ap[pp] + '</option>';
            }
            output += '</select>';              

            // hide original input and append new replacement inputs
            $(this).attr('type','hidden').after(output);
        });

        $('select.timepicker').change(function(){
            var i = this.id.substr(2);
            var h = $('#h_' + i).val();
            var m = $('#m_' + i).val();
            var p = $('#p_' + i).val();
            var v = h + ':' + m + p;
            $('#' + i).val(v);
        });

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);



/* SVN: $Id: jquery.timepicker.js 456 2007-07-16 19:09:57Z Jason Huck $ */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="timepicker"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#timepicker').timepicker();
});
</script>
```

**install jquery library at header**

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Is that a sample script below.

**Demo**

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uJ8XV/)

Comment: I am unable to get the time fields

Comment: @saplingPro you need install the jquery library, if not you above timepicker function will not able run.

Comment: still not running. I included these in head `<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.timepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @saplingPro, You want know more about jquery tutorial from [W3School-Jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/default.asp)

Comment: Is this the jquery library you mentioned http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js ?

Comment: correct @saplingPro, you can save as jquery-1.11.0.min.js to your host.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should load scripts in the FOOTER -- not the `<head>` section. -- that is so 90's.  :)  -- Plenty of resources online as to why --- [HERE IS ONE](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydnfiveblog/high-performance-sites-rule-6-move-scripts-bottom-7200.html)

Comment: @SanuelJackson, agree with you, script load at footer is new method. If using htmltidy, it also suggest put at footer. But some time i need to put at header for some cases.

Comment: @CheongBC - The only time you should ever *need* to put it in the header is if the HTML flow is not controlled (aka, WordPress), or simply too lazy to scroll and paste at the bottom.  Overall, it is a good habit to get into, and makes pages on the Internet much friendlier and faster content than the original method.

Comment: @CheongBC - not a problem.  I still adjusting to the habit as well. One good thing to have if loading a lot of images/etc, is to hide the body and display a page-loader while many images/etc are loading.

Answer (score 2):

In the HTML

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker" name="foo" />
```

In the footer, include the javascript, then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.timepicker').timepicker();
});
```

This assumes that you are loading jQuery, and write the rest of the HTML.

It is also using a non-existant (maybe) class named 'timepicker' so it can readily be used to assign this capability to more than one field at the same time just by adding that class to each input.  You can also use `<div>`, but I am assuming you want the input in a `<form>`

### LOAD ORDER EXAMPLE

```
<html>
 <head>
   ...
 </head>
 <body>
   ...
   <form ... >
   ...

   <input type="text" class="timepicker" name="foo" />

   ...
   </form>
   ...
 </body>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="WHATEVER_YOU_NAMED_TIMEPICKER.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.timepicker').timepicker();
   });
 </script>

</html>
```

Comment: I do not get the time fields

Comment: Basically, the difference between `Cheong BC` and my answer is he wrapped the javascript in `<script></script>` tags, which I assumed you would be doing given this is JavaScript ^.^

Comment: I don't get the either way

Comment: The other script should be stored in it's own file, then use `<script type="text/javascript" src="timepicker.js"></script>` AFTER jQuery itself is included -- will edit answer to clarify the order for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have use below Jquery Library

```
    <html>
 <head>
   ...
 </head>
 <body>
   ...
   <form ... >
   ...

   <input type="text" class="timepicker" name="timepicker" />

   ...
   </form>
   ...
 </body>

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.timepicker').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
            interval: 30,
            minTime: '10',
            maxTime: '6:00pm',
            defaultTime: '11',
            startTime: '10:00',
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true
         });
   });
 </script>

</html>
```